# Install NPM package if not installed using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shell script to install NPM package if not already installed.

I can use the command `npm info <package-name> version` to get information about the package. It gives me the version if it is already there

```
2.0.0
```

If it is not there it gives an error.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not found :<package>
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '<package>' is not in the npm registry.
```

How can I use this result in a conditional block to do some task depending on it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating things. `npm-install` already checks if the module is installed and just ignores it if it's already there, so all you need to do is call it:

```
$ npm install mymodule@2.0.0
```

Comment: My application has several dependencies. I am writing a script to automate installing those dependencies rather than expecting the user to install them manually. So, this is a real requirement for me.

Comment: @Malintha Why reinvent the wheel? Why not have a `dependencies` section in your `package.json` and let NPM do the heavy lifting for you?